# Shafarevich Exercise 1.10. Find all the automorphisms of the curve $y^2 = x^3 + x^2$

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I get stuck on finding all automorphisms of the curve $y^2 = x^3 + x^2$.

I tried to use homogeneous coordinates: $
\zeta \eta^2 = \xi^3 + \zeta \xi^2$, $x = \xi/\zeta, y=\eta/\zeta$.

There is one singular point $(0,0,1)$.
Could someone  help how to proceed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Note**: I made some silly errors originally, now corrected.

I hope you’ve drawn the picture.

I like to give this curve (but not this question) to Calculus students, when they learn about parametric description of curves. Here, you take a line passing through the origin, $y=tx$, and see that it intersects the curve in three points, as it must, namely the origin counted twice and $(t^2-1,t^3-t)$.

Find the automorphisms of the affine line (or projective line, if you’re working projectively) that leave $\pm1$ fixed (or maybe exchange the two) and you’ve solved the problem.

Comment: you mean $(t^2-1,t^3-1)$?

Comment: No, since those do not satisfy $y^2=x^3+x^2$, and that $y$ is not $t$ times that $x$.

Comment: I do apologize for making a mess of this at first. You deserved better.

Comment: I just want to be sure that I solved it correct. As the birational automorphism of projective line is $x -> \frac{ax+b}{cx+d}$ (stated in Shafarevich), then the automorphisms on projective line has 2 fixed points (the roots of $x(cx+d)=ax+b$). So as we need to have  $\pm1$ fixed then for projective line it could be $x -> \frac{2x+3}{3x+2}$. Is it correct?

Comment: I think so. If you like, you may put the two fixed points at zero and infinity; then your automorphisms simply become  $x\mapsto\lambda x$ .  In other words there is a one-parameter family of such automorphisms.