# The method finding automorphisms of algebraic curves .e.g $y^2=x^3$

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I can't find in AG books how to find automorphisms of curves. 
As example cusp curve  $y^2=x^3$.

I'll be appreciated for small example, explanation or a book where I can read it.

Comment: Hint: If $\sigma$ is an automorphism of a $k$-algebra $A$, $k$ a field and $A$ a domain, then it induces an automorphism of the integral closure of $A$. In your case, the integral closure of $k[x,y]/(y^2-x^3)$ is $k[t]$, with $y=t^3, x=t^2$. You know all automorphisms of $k[t]$, so work backwards.

Comment: You can try the strategy in [this similar post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3049558/) with the parametrization given by Mohan.